# SQL Assistance with math query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Screenshot for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UH1B.png)

I'm trying to get the answer for the following question for an hour and I need help:

Write a query that returns a field called below_250 that lists all states with an avg_math_4_score less than 250 over all states in the year 2000.

What am I doing wrong?
Failed attempt below

```
WITH AVR_ST AS
    (SELECT avg(avg_math_4_score) AS AVG_STATES
    FROM naep
    WHERE year = '2000'
    GROUP BY state)
SELECT DISTINCT state AS below_250
FROM naep, AVR_ST
WHERE 250 < AVG_STATES;
```

Error below:

```
There was an error with the SQL query:

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function avg() does not exist
LINE 4: WHERE avg_math_4_score > (select AVG())) AS "t1" LIMIT 1
                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: You got your comparison reversed for one. Mostly you just need a `having` clause after the `group by`.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You cannot start SQL statement with the expression (which is subquery in your case), so you have to get average per state at the first step and then apply `having` clause. Please, chech the documentation for your DBMS for the syntax. It should be learnt by yourself. Also please describe, what is the issue you have with your current attempt, not just "it doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry, I entered my query wrong. I didn't fence in the code properly. Code revised.

Comment: What is `avg_math_4_score`? Please, show sample data. Looks like you even do not need any aggregation at all.

Comment: Please add your schema

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis after the CTE definition. You've already grouped by state so there will be not duplicates: `distinct` is unnecessary. You only need to refer to one table in the main select (the CTE).

Comment: Added a screenshot for ref. I'm a noob so please ELI5. Appreciate everyones help!

Comment: It's not a good sign when one has to look up the acronym asking for a specific kind of help.

Comment: English is not my first language, sorry. I will improve!

Comment: Year is a numeric, per your screenshot. Also remove the quotes from the literal year.

Comment: Your error message does not match the query at all. Please edit the question to be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts to redirect OP in comments it became apparent that OP was unable to understand the points highlighted. It was easiest to make the corrections as an answer with actual code.

```
WITH AVR_ST AS (
    SELECT state, avg(avg_math_4_score) AS AVG_STATES
    FROM naep
    WHERE year = 2000
    GROUP BY state
)
SELECT state AS below_250
FROM AVR_ST
WHERE 250 > AVG_STATES;
```

Despite OP's apparent success. SO moderators have taken it upon themselves to remind me why I keep stepping away from contributing. Sure this isn't going to ever be useful to anybody else, regardless of whether it remains "code-only". From that standpoint I don't object to removing it entirely. But when my efforts are insulted as low quality then it's time to pack up.

Comment: There was an error with the SQL query:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "state" does not exist
LINE 7: SELECT state AS below_250
               ^

Comment: @MariaVarges There's no error mentioned.

Comment: Revised sorry. Edited showing error

Comment: Check now. The column wasn't being returned in the CTE.

Comment: There was an error with the SQL query:

Error - PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "avg_states" does not exist
LINE 9: WHERE 250 > AVG_STATES) AS "t1" LIMIT 1

Comment: It was line 2, i modified it to match line 9.  THANK YOU!

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: @stephen, it works because it's valid syntax. There's nothing more to elaborate. Boilerplate text and thought is of no higher quality either.